# Google Cross-Origin Request

Tags: javascript, google-api, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am trying to use Google JS API from my HTML page and I have to do something like:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_API_KEY"/>
```

But I am getting the following error:

Firefox:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_API_KEY.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_API_KEY. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

As I have read it is caused by browsers restrictions to crossed request but I have no clue about how to fix it so I can do that request. Can anyone give me a tip?

Comment: How is this jsf related?

Comment: @Kukeltje since my code is JSF and I am trying to access it from there

Comment: Sure, but your code runs in a specific browsers and you did not add those as a tag and most of jsf is **server** side and this is client-side. And your PC uses an operating system and you did not add that either... And... summary: tags are for where the problem is, not what you use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it changing the way I made the request:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_API_KEY",
        crossDomain: true,
        method: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'script',
        headers:{
            "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
        }
    });
</script>
```